# Prove that $n\binom{2n-1}{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}^2$

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove that $n\binom{2n-1}{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}^2$

I know that using the Chu-Vandermonde Identity will help to solve this, but I'm not seeing how.

Comment: induction will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We count committees of $n$ people selected from $n$ mathematicians and $n$ statisticians whose chairperson is a mathematician in two ways.

There are $n$ ways to choose a mathematician to be a chairperson and $\binom{2n - 1}{n - 1}$ ways to choose $n - 1$ of the remaining $2n - 1$ people to serve on the committee.  Hence, the number of such committees is 
$$n\binom{2n - 1}{n - 1}$$

We can choose such a committee by selecting $k$ of the $n$ mathematicians and $n - k$ of the $n$ statisticians, then selecting the chairperson from among the $k$ mathematicians.  The number of such committees with exactly $k$ mathematicians and $n - k$ statisticians is 
$$k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n - k} = k\binom{n}{k}^2$$
Hence, the total number of such committees is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} k\binom{n}{k}^2$$ 
Since we have counted the same set of committees in two ways, we may conclude that 
$$n\binom{2n - 1}{n - 1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} k\binom{n}{k}^2$$

Answer (score 0):

We use the identity
$$
k\binom{n}{k}=\binom{k}{1}\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\tag{1}.
$$
Then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}^2=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}
&=n\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{n}{n-k}\tag{by 1}\\
&=n\sum_{u = 0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{u}\binom{n}{n-1-u}\\
&=n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}
\end{align*}
by Vandermonde's identity.

Answer (score 0):

Use $ \binom {n}{k} = [x^k] : (1+x)^n$ and $ k \binom{n}{k}= n \binom{n-1}{k-1} $
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom{n}{k}^2 &=& \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom{n}{k} [x^k]:  (1+x)^n \\
&=&  [x^n]: \sum_{k=1}^{n} n \binom{n-1}{k-1} x^{n-k} (1+x)^n \\
&=&  [x^n]:  n  (1+x)^{2n-1} = n  \binom{2n-1}{n-1} .\\
\end{eqnarray*}